# Local web server

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to create a local web server and different domains for eg. apple.com,abc.apple.com,xyz.apple.com etc.I installed LAMP in CentOS 5.4. The problem is i am not able to configure ssh username and password for each of my subdomain.I want to keep a single document root for each subdomain.
      can anybody explain the whole process of setting a local web server with multiple subdomain having unique ssh username and password  with common document root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**

> "create a local web server and different domains for eg.
>   apple.com,abc.apple.com,xyz.apple.com"

Set up [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/) on the Apache httpd server. Edit httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName apple.com
  DocumentRoot /www/apple
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.apple.com
  DocumentRoot /www/abc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xyz.apple.com
  DocumentRoot /www/xyz
</VirtualHost>
```

**2**

> "configure ssh username and password for each of my subdomain"

First, set up users to maintain the content of each site. There are a number of ways of handling this. One way would be to make apache serve each site from a subdirectory of each users home directory. Another way would be to put a softlink from the user's home directory to the docroot directory of the corresponding site.

```
useradd ... mary
mkdir /www/apple
chown mary /www/apple
ln -s /www/apple ~mary/html

useradd ... fred
mkdir /www/abc
chown fred /www/abc
ln -s /www/abc ~fred/html

useradd ... pete
mkdir /www/xyz
chown pete /www/xyz
ln -s /www/xyz ~pete/html
```

Then you set up ssh in the usual way. When Mary, Fred or Pete log in they can `cd html` and edit the content for the website they have responsibility for.apple.com,abc.apple.com,xyz.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

also put entries in hosts file for each domain to point to your server